# How to send data from android application to asp.net webservices

Tags: android, asp.net, send

I had develop a one android application and now I want to send data from my android application by clicking on submit button and that data will be print in asp.net website

Please give a sample for both android application and asp.net website.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We appreciate you taking efforts to solve your problem. You can start in this direction by looking at [ksoap-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/). Please give me the codes, won't get you a lot of answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should search some exapmle before asking any question...neways
You can go through this exapmle [How to Call Web Service in Android Using SOAP](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/)

also you can do it using JSON see [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)